# How to refresh the DataSource of a ComboBox when database is updated?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a ComboBox with some DataSource. Some names are not in the list, and when I add them by displaying another Form, then I am not getting those items in my ComboBox.

I want to show those items when the "client add" Form is closed.

I am using this code:

```
AddClient ob = new AddClient();

ob.Show();

if (DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
{ 
    List<AddBatteryType> btry = db.AddBatteryTypes.ToList();
    comboBoxBatteryType.DataSource = btry;
    comboBoxBatteryType.DisplayMember = "Type";
    comboBoxBatteryType.ValueMember = "Id";
}
```

Comment: How is the actual data being updated in the database?  It's not clear where you're getting that `DialogResult`, or in what order these things are happening.

Answer (score 1):

You're not waiting for the other Form to close, so the `if` statement is immediately evaluated after showing the `AddClient` form. The value of `DialogResult` is `None`, so the code inside the `if` block does not execute.

Change this:

```
ob.Show();        // execution continues as soon as the second form is shown
```

To this:

```
ob.ShowDialog();  // execution stops here until the second form is closed
```

That being said, the code inside the `if` block doesn't reference the Form you're displaying at all, so there doesn't seem to be a purpose for displaying it... unless there's code inside that Form that's saving values to the `AddBatteryType` table in your database.

Answer (score 0):

To go with Grant's answer, after changing to showdialog, you will also need to check the DialogResult property of ob, instead of the DialogResult of the current form you're in.

if (ob.DialogResult == ...)